# Error While Installing MiKTeX

Tags: errors, miktex, installing

I'm a newbie in the whole TeX-&-LaTeX-based world, and I'm trying to install MiKTeX right now.

My OS is Windows 10 Pro, 64-bit.

I had MiKTeX, LaTeX, and LyX previously installed.
I uninstalled them via the **Change or Remove a Program of Windows**.

The file I downloaded was
[Basic MiKTeX Installer, 64-bit](http://pastebin.com/4nszSy2B).
After downloading it, I started the installation, and got these errors:

1. I first got a pop-up error:

   [image]
2. I pressed "OK", and it took me back to the installer, where it showed me another error:

   [image]

I repeated this process about 2-3 times, and in all of them, I had all the folders of MiKTeX, from what it seemed to me. And, And, in every single time, I got those errors.

In the error message of the pop-up, it mentioned a log file. After I installed MiKTeX for the first 2-3 times, where everything seemed to be installed, I went to that log file, and it was empty.

I don't know if the installation happened successfully in the previous times, since I got the same errors every single time, but now, I'm sure that it didn't.

Now, the only folders & files that I have are:

1. `miktex`

   2. `config`

      3. `setup-2016-11-17-16-06.log` which you can view [here](http://pastebin.com/4nszSy2B)

As opposed, like I said, to all of the folders that were installed, that seemed to be like they are all of what should be after a successful installation - folders like `pdflatex` and others.

How can I fix this?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) MiKTeX has been undergoing some refactoring and this seems to have generated a few issues.  Try taking the latest version of the installer from http://miktex.org/download and trying again if that doesn't work maybe you should check [recent bugs](https://sourceforge.net/p/miktex/bugs/) for overlap with your problem or consider filing a bug report yourself (especially if you can replicate this on multiple machines).

Comment: If there's urgency you could always try installing [TeXLive](https://www.tug.org/texlive/) instead.

Comment: @DaiBowen Thank you. :)

I did take latest version. I'll check the recent bugs. Thanks for the information. :)

TeXLive won't help me, since I'm trying to install MiKTeX to get LyX working, but thanks for the recommendation. I wasn't familiar with it.

Comment: (A bit off-topic) I'm neither a LyX nor (very much) a TeXLive user but I'd be very surprised if TeXLive didn't do the job for LyX.  https://wiki.lyx.org/Windows/Windows seems to suggest MiKTeX or TeXLive is fine.

Comment: Does this problem still present itself with the latest version of the MiKTeX installer?

Comment: @DaiBowen, I don't know. I haven't tried reinstalling a 64-bit disribution of MikTeX on a 64-bit version of Windows. As I said, 64-bit distributions of MiKTeX work on Windows on 64-bit (I'm running one right now), so at least that works. If you're going to try installing one, I'd like to know.

Comment: @DaiBowen Just for info: I sometimes use LyX, and I have a TeXLive distribution on  Windows 10, and it works.